# Using AJAX to refresh two different textboxes

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've got a page that retrieves two values from the database (`Atender` and `Posto`).

I'd like to refresh a `textbox1` with `Atender` value and `textbox2` with `Posto` value. At the moment, I'm only able to make it so this function refreshes 1 value or the 2 values simultaneously, but both values show up on the two textboxes.

EDIT: Forgot to add, the PHP you see there is the PainelUtilizador.php. Same goes for the HTML, all of that code is inside PainelUtilizador.php

Here's my code, I'm sure you'll be able to know what I mean after taking a look:

```html
<?php
include '../Login/db_login.php';

if(isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
$sql1 = "SELECT Atender,Posto FROM atendercliente WHERE ID=1";
$sql2 = "SELECT Atender,Posto FROM atendercliente WHERE ID=2";
$resultA = $conn->query($sql1);
   while($row = $resultA->fetch_assoc()) {
  $returnArrayA = array('AtenderA' => $row["Atender"], 'PostoA' => $row["Posto"]);
   };
$resultB = $conn->query($sql2);
   while($row = $resultB->fetch_assoc()) {
  $returnArrayB = array('AtenderB' => $row["Atender"], 'PostoB' => $row["Posto"]);
   };
   echo json_encode($returnArrayA);
   echo json_encode($returnArrayB);exit;
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Painel do utilizador</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax('PainelUtilizador.php?ajax=1').done(function(data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    $("#refreshASenha").val(data['Atender']);
                    $("#refreshAPosto").val(data['Posto']);
               $("#refreshBSenha").val(data['Atender']);
                    $("#refreshBPosto").val(data['Posto']);
                })
            }, 1000);
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td> <input type="text" id="refreshASenha" disabled> </td>
  <td> <input type="text" id="refreshAPosto" disabled> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td> <input type="text" id="refreshBSenha" disabled> </td>
  <td> <input type="text" id="refreshBPosto" disabled> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm still a beginner, and am still learning AJAX and JQuery by myself

Comment: what is written in `PainelUtilizador.php`

Comment: Forgot to add, the PHP you see there is the PainelUtilizador.php. Same goes for the HTML, all of that code is inside PainelUtilizador.php

Comment: added the answer. it uses only one ajax instead of two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a check for ajax & then call the DB method only. You can simply do it in one ajax rather than calling two

**UPDATE**

```html
<?php
include '../Login/db_login.php';

if(isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
$sql1 = "SELECT Atender,Posto FROM atendercliente WHERE ID=1";
$sql2 = "SELECT Atender,Posto FROM atendercliente WHERE ID=2";
$resultA = $conn->query($sql1);
   while($row = $resultA->fetch_assoc()) {
     $returnArrayA = array('Atender' => $row["Atender"], 'Posto' => $row["Posto"]);
   };
$resultB = $conn->query($sql2);
   while($row = $resultB->fetch_assoc()) {
     $returnArrayB = array('Atender' => $row["Atender"], 'Posto' => $row["Posto"]);
   };
   echo json_encode(array('A' => $returnArrayA, 'B' => $returnArrayB));exit;
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Painel do utilizador</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            setInterval(function(){
                $.ajax('PainelUtilizador.php?ajax=1').done(function(data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    $("#refreshASenha").val(data['A']['Atender']);
                    $("#refreshAPosto").val(data['A']['Posto']);
      $("#refreshBSenha").val(data['B']['Atender']);
                    $("#refreshBPosto").val(data['B']['Posto']);
                })
            }, 1000);
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td> <input type="text" id="refreshASenha" disabled> </td>
  <td> <input type="text" id="refreshAPosto" disabled> </td>
</tr>
</table>
<table border="1">
<tr>
  <td> <input type="text" id="refreshBSenha" disabled> </td>
  <td> <input type="text" id="refreshBPosto" disabled> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It does return both values, but on a blank page "{"Atender":"5","Posto":"4"}". Does not return them inside the textboxes

Comment: what url you are using. don't add `ajax` to your current url. i have added that in case of `ajax request` only. it will be called via ajax only

Comment: Wonderful, it works flawlessly! Can you tell me just one more thing? I'll need to do a few more queries, same principle as that one except I have to change the ID, how could I add those query results to new textboxes? Is the principle the same?

Comment: create an array in the php & use the same logic, just add the `ID` in the array key like this `$returnArray[] = array('id' => $id, 'Atender' => $row["Atender"], 'Posto' => $row["Posto"]);` Now in ajax, loop the response & then use like `$("#refreshASenha" + data['id']).val(data['Atender']);`. Make sure your input has the same id like `<td> <input type="text" id="refreshASenha1" disabled> </td>`

Comment: Sorry for annoying you, but I've tried to do what you said, but I most likely did it wrong. Can you tell me what's wrong just this one more time?

Comment: I have added an updated answer. Can you tell me if these ids can be increased?

Comment: Just perfect. Thanks a lot!